# How safe is it to leave soup food out?

Tags: food-safety, soup, spoilage

I'm well aware that bacteria can grow on food left out overnight and should probably be thrown out afterwards. But, what about in instance of soups or stews, where the soup/stew goes directly from the cooked pot to a CLOSED pyrex container.

I would think since the food is starting off quite hot and immediately put in a air-tight container it is semi-akin to the canning process.

So all in all is there any scientific evidence that would allow me to believe that the way this food was "left out" is safe or nearly safe?

Comment: The food safety guidelines are very clear. Your closed or open container doesn't matter. Please see the duplicate-target to read about basic food safety.

Comment: When canning, the container and lid is boiled to sterilize it in addition to the food getting cooked, and then it's heated more once the food is in the jar and the lid goes on to get as much air as possible out of the container. (Depending on the acidity of the food in question, pressure processing may be required.) Your scenario is _similar_ to canning, but leaves out two or three important safety steps.